# lightslider - Disable next slide if getcookie is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I handle the next slide is active if the condition is valid?

Flow:

I have 2 button: single and married, in case the button not yet clicked, lightslider allowing to go to next slide, I want to set it will able to next if the condition is valid

JS

```
$('#goToNextSlide').on('click', function () {
    slider.goToNextSlide();
    $('.sliderControl > a.prev > i').removeClass('disable');
    var slideCount = slider.getCurrentSlideCount();
    if(slideCount == 2 && getCookie("Gender")==''){
      console.log("blabalalaba"); \\this line for handling the slide, but i dont know how to disable next slide
    }
    if(slideCount == 6){
      Triangle();
        $('.sliderControl > a.next > i').addClass('disable');
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to add more code and if possible make link of JSFiddle

Comment: @HarshPatel I dont know how to use jsfiddle, and i cant add more code because SOF rules says my post have too much code

Comment: @HarshPatel i've edit someone jsfiddle, take a look please https://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/5528/